# Having done something vs doing something

Tags: past-tense

Do these two sentences mean the same thing? If not, please elaborate. If there are grammar mistakes, please help me correct them.

1. Growing up in California, I experienced life that was different than most people in Mexico.
2. Having grown up in California, I experienced life different than most people in Mexico.

Comment: Thanks. I will post a similar question on English Language Learners.

Comment: Your explanation is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These mean the same thing. I think they are slightly better with "a life" instead of just "life". We use "a life" where we are referring to some major portion of our existence, like our entire growing-up period or our life as a whole. "Experiencing life" implies dealing with the realities of whatever world you've inhabited, as opposed to just having the experiences through the period.

It isn't a large difference, but enough that I missed the article in the original.